# JavaScript and Flash incompatibility with IE

Tags: php, javascript, flash, flash-cs4

I have a JavaScript Picture gallery. The arrows under the gallery make possible to move through all pictures of the gallery. When I have added to that page also a .SWF flash animation the gallery arrows stoped working properly in IE. But in other browsers like Mozilla, Google Chrome, Opera and so on it works! I have removed the .SWF and it is working in IE as well.

Here is the code where I have instantiated the .SW:

```
<embed src="ads/banner.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="770" height="180" style="margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px hidden; outline:0px; overflow:hidden; background-color:#c2c6c9;"></embed>
```

Please help me to understand at this time what's wrong with IE. :)

Comment: You're going to need to include some code...

Comment: A more easily answered question is "What ISN'T wrong with IE?" ... The answer, nothing! :)

Comment: My question has that nuance :), fucla!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support `<embed>`; it hasn't since IE 5.5. See [KB303401](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303401).

[Some discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499432/is-there-a-standard-copy-paste-way-to-safely-put-a-swf-in-a-web-page) of Flash embedding strategies.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the proper syntax which Adobe explains here:

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html

which is:

```
<OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" WIDTH="550" HEIGHT="400" id="myMovieName">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="myFlashMovie.swf">
<PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high>
<PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#FFFFFF>
<EMBED href="/support/flash/ts/documents/myFlashMovie.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF WIDTH="550" HEIGHT="400" NAME="myMovieName" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</EMBED>
</OBJECT>
```