# html flash embed

Tags: html, flash, embed

I use the below code within  for my JQuery lightbox without include js file AC_RunActiveContent.js or swfobject-1.5.js in the html file. It works fine for IE and Firefox. Just wanna know if there is any problem for not include AC_RunActiveContent.js or swfobject-1.5.js. Is it a must to have AC_RunActiveContent.js or swfobject-1.5.js for display a flash properly in different browsers version?

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="789" height="617" id="Loader" align="middle">
 <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
 <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
 <param name="movie" value="en_MAIN.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /> 
    <embed src="en_MAIN.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="789" height="617" name="Loader" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that's the Adobe-style standard markup. It works across all current browsers.

It's ugly, doesn't validate and has to state each parameter twice, which is what the Flash embedding scripts you mention are attempting to address (plus sometimes also there's an IE ‘object activation’ workaround that is no longer necessary). If you don't care about that, you're fine as you are. If you do, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499432/is-there-a-standard-copy-paste-way-to-safely-put-a-swf-in-a-web-page) has some discussion on alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is connected to Lightbox: AC_RunActiveContent.js and swfobject-1.5.js are javascript workarounds for getting Flash to work in IE. Since Lightbox uses JQuery, not Flash, you shouldn't need them.

Look closely at the [lightbox instructions](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) for more information.